# Cannot install jasmine-core on Windows 7 / OSX

Tags: npm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to install `karma-jasmine` on Windows 7 / Git Bash, according to these guidelines: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/installation.html

However, the installation fails for `jasmine-core`:

```
$ npm install karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
ngut@1.0.0 g:\SW Engineering\ngUT
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
├─┬ karma-chrome-launcher@0.2.2
│ ├─┬ fs-access@1.0.0
│ │ └── null-check@1.0.0
│ └─┬ which@1.2.0
│   └─┬ is-absolute@0.1.7
│     └── is-relative@0.1.3
└── karma-jasmine@0.3.6

npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but
none was installed.
```

I tried the installation first with Cygwin, only to learn that `npm` is not supported on Cygwin, but there the failing dependency was `fsevent`.

The global installation of `jasmine-core` succeeds, but I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/19/karma-angularjs-testing/)  and `karma start karma.conf.js` fails for the same reason (missing `jasmine-core`) with the global installation as well.

Finally, the exact same problem appears on OSX as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma v.0.13.16 just did not support v.5.3.0 of Node. The supported Node versions were listed on Karma installation page.

Comment: Well, imho the capital sin of the Karma installation page is that it tells to install karma-jasmine, but not jasmine-core. The problem you (and I) encountered can be overcome by **installing manually jasmine-core**. Apparently the karma-jasmine dependencies on Windows are not handled well by npm.

Comment: You can try 
setx CHROME_BIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /M