# Cannot install karma-jasmine and phantomjs on Windows 8.1 - what can I do to get it to work?

Tags: npm, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

My Question is a little bit different from 
[Cannot install jasmine-core on Windows 7 / OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379469/cannot-install-jasmine-core-on-windows-7-osx)

I tried this command:

```
npm install karma karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

I saw in the answer that Karma is not supporting v.5.3.0 of Node (it seems to be the same with my version v.5.2.0 ).

But what can i do? The quoted thread is not giving any answer to solve the problem... Downgrade node and every package I have installed?? How to? Is this working? I am new to these technologies.

Here are the errors I got:

```
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY phantomjs@>=1.9

npm WARN karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.2 requires a peer of phantomjs@>=1.9 but none was installed.
```

Another problem is

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6
```

So what can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a pair of missing npm modules. Install them:

```
npm install jasmine --save-dev
npm install phantomjs --save-dev
```

OTOH, according to the FAQs, karma 0.13 runs on node 5.x. [See the last FAQ here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

JotaBe's solution did not quite work for me. karma-jasmine installed OK. But I still got errors on karma-phantomjs-launcher.

The following worked for me:

```
npm install jasmine --save-dev
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt --save
```